# Continuously watch for a variable change without render in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I want to update a component and call a function when a specific date is reached.
Basically, I want to do:

```
 if(moment().unix()==end_date){
   myFunction
 }
```

For the moment, I'm doing this inside the componentDidUpdate function, but the component has to be update to check if the condition is true. I want it to be automatic...
But I don't want to render my component continuously (the end-date can be in many days)
Is there a way to continuously check a variable without render the component?

I also try to do that after the render:

```
render{
 if(moment().unix()==end_date){
   myFunction
 }
 return(...)
}
```

But as above, I have to render my component to update the condition (I wonder if there is a difference in the use between these two methods and if one is to be avoided?)

Thanks